# How to clear iCloud Music Library?

Tags: itunes, icloud, music

I didn't know this iCloud Music Library thing was automatically turned on in iTunes on my iMac. I do like this feature but I only want to have it turned on with my Macbook and iPhone. Now I have a lot of tracks from my iMac mostly recording or audiobooks that cluster up my iCloud Music Library. I don't see an option to clear the iCloud Music Library, and manually deleting 1,201 tracks would take me two and half hours. Is there a way to remove all tracks from iCloud Music Library?

Comment: It wasn't turned on automatically. It asked you at some point - you said Yes.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of deleting tracks one by one, you could take another approach.  Select a genre, delete it (that is, all the tracks of that genre), and repeat.